# Hibernate JTable Optimistic Locking

Tags: mysql, swing, hibernate

I think about how to implement the following feature:

JTable with **CustomTableModel** connected to **MYSQL** database using **Hibernate** and optimistic locking.

The function **setValueAt** checks whether the version attribute has changed,
if not I would like to open an **JDialog** to allow the user to decide whether the old record or his new record should be saved.

How would you call a JDialog from my CustomTableModel setValueAt Method ?

Thanks for suggestions !

Comment: i do not really understand the question. i would call the dialog in just the regular way. Means: display modal dialog -> after dialog is closed, ask the dialog what happened.

Comment: Yes I am just trying to avoid mixing JDialog (GUI code) with the JTable model and I thought that there might be a differen way.

Comment: You could create Interfaces and use different Design-Patterns, to avoid using JDialog-Code in your TableModel-Impl. But at the end, it will result  in an dialog, which is invoked (in any way) from your TableModel.

Comment: Ok thanks yor your suggestions.